# Understanding Code Behavior and Variable Names in Recursive Binary Tree Manipulation

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working on LeetCode problem 1325, "Delete Leaves With a Given Value," and I've come across an issue in my code that I'm trying to understand.

In my code, I'm implementing a recursive approach to remove leaf nodes with a given target value in a binary tree. I've noticed a difference in behavior when I return `root` directly in the main function compared to when I return the result of the `dfs` function.

Here are the two code snippets for reference:

**ISSUE 1:**

**Code Snippet 1: Returning `root` directly**

```py
def removeLeafNodes(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], target: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    def dfs(root, target):
        if root is None:
            return None
        root.left = dfs(root.left, target)
        root.right = dfs(root.right, target)
        if not root.left and not root.right and root.val == target:
            root = None
            return 
        return root
    dfs(root, target)
    return root
```

**Code Snippet 2: Returning the result of `dfs`**

```py
def removeLeafNodes(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], target: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
    def dfs(root, target):
        if root is None:
            return None
        root.left = dfs(root.left, target)
        root.right = dfs(root.right, target)
        if not root.left and not root.right and root.val == target:
            root = None
            return 
        return root
    return dfs(root, target)
```

My question is: What is the difference in behavior between returning `root` directly in the main function and returning the result of the `dfs` function? Why does the first approach not work as expected in certain cases, like `[1,1]`, where it converts the tree to [1] instead of the expected empty tree `[]`?

**Issue 2: Variable Names in Recursive Code**

I also noticed an interesting issue with variable names. When I initially used `root.left` and `root.right` in the recursive function, the code ran correctly. However, when I tried to change the variable names to `root_left` and `root_right` like this:

```py
root_left = dfs(root.left, target)
root_right = dfs(root.right, target)
```

The code started failing for all test cases.

My question is: Shouldn't variable names like `root_left` and `root_right` be just reference holders for the same values? What might be causing this unexpected behavior when I change the variable names?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: You say "I've noticed a difference in behavior" and then ask "What is the difference in behavior", which sounds like you already *know* the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the case when this code executes:

```
        if not root.left and not root.right and root.val == target:
            root = None
            return
```

This is assigning the local variable `root` in the `dfs()` function, not the variable in the main function. So when the main function then does `return root`, it returns the original value of `root` rather than `None`.